# What is the difference between 'center' and 'centerCrop' in the "ImageView"?

Tags: android, xml

`1-android:scaleTaype="center"`

`2-android:scaleTaype="centerCrop"`

What is the difference between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 8):

**CENTER** :- Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.

[image]

**CENTER_CROP** :- Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. 
[image]

Refer to [this official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) for a overview of all the *ScaleTypes* and [this site](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html) for a detailed explanation